Is an adjective justified in the place of the subject in a sentence?
I am an ESL Chinese student in China. And I wonder whether it is standard to put an adjective in the place of the subject. Subject is always noun phrases including infinitives, gerunds and noun clauses as most grammar books will tell me. But there are indeed some exceptions I encountered, some of which I assumed might be nonstandard, or should only occur in colloquial expressions:

Well begun is half done.
Slow and steady wins the race.
Born blind is tough in any case.
We all know fresh is best when it comes to food.

The first two sentences are proverbial expressions and the last two sentences are sentences I saw in my English test papers or workbooks. It's obvious there's no inversion in the sentences above, but they all take adjective as subjects.
Would you be so kind as to explain this for me? Plus, if you think the grammar is wrong, is there any better substitutes of yours? Thanks.

I wouldn't say it was standard, but it is acceptable in proverbial expressions and slogans (like Fresh is best).  The subject is implied (A task well done, a competitor who is slow and steady, fresh food).  No. 3 is unconventional - I would expect "Being born blind..."

Handsome is as handsome does gets its own dictionary entry. But I've always found the syntax "unusual" in that one.

This question is similar to: Can an adjective be a subject. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In these examples the adjective stands for the state of being whatever that adjective implies, as in "[being] born blind is tough in any case", "We all know [being] fresh is best when it comes to food".

Yes, but …
Yes, adjectives can be the subject of a sentence but they become nominalised. That is, there is an implied noun but the adjective cannot be separated from it. Or, maybe these are adverbs and there is an implied and integral verb. “Well begun” and “slow and steady” could be describing the actor (adjective-noun) or the act (adverb-verb).
Or, sometimes, they are a an abbreviation for a more complete phrase - “Born blind” = “Being born blind”.
Or, being displaced from the noun they are modifying - “fresh is best when it comes to food” = “fresh food is best”. Although, “fresh is best” is probably idiomatic.
Sorry, English plays fast and loose with forms of speech.
